# ActionBarDrawrToggleButton appearing on top corner in android 3.0

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have created action bar using `android.app.ActionBar` in android 3.0 API 11. I have created a `NavigationDrawer` in the layout using `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`.

I have also specified  `ActionBarDrawerToggle` (`android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`) button to switch between drawerLayout .

But after running this on emulator (android 3.0 API 11), `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is appearing in the top left corner aligning even at the top corner of action bar. It should be aligned vertically center just before the app icon.

In the later versions of emulator, it is working fine, appearing vertically center as it should be. Only problem while running on API 11, android 3.0.

[image]

I want to use only this ActionBar, not the toolbar provided in the support library.

Please help me with this `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Thanks.

Comment: Most of the navigation modes in ActionBar is deprecated. Also, ActionBarDrawerToggle (v4) is deprecated. Use the v7 one. I would recommend you to use the Toolbar instead of ActionBar.

Comment: Thanks @RafiduzzamanSonnet & Rami. I changed the code to use v7 appCompat ActionBar. There may be something wrong with toggle button on API 11.

Comment: Nobody's using API 11 through 13. Stop wasting your time testing on these. Even the source code is not available. If you need to support older phones, test on API 10. If not, test on API 15 (all Android 4 devices), 17 (Android 4.2 and above, 80% Android devices worldwide as of now), 19 (Android 4.4 KitKat), 21 (Android 5 Lollipop), 23 (Android 6 Marshmallow).